# Vertically centering a popover div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make an iPad-like popover div as an exercise, but I can't find out how to vertically center the popover div, having an unspecified content width/height.

http://jsfiddle.net/mbYyR/5/

I want the triangle to point to the position defined by #popover-wrapper's top/bottom right/left values, but `top: -50%` does not work.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Could you move the CSS code out of the style attributes and into jsFiddle's CSS box on the right? That would improve the readability of your code...

Comment: Separated CSS and HTML, see: http://jsfiddle.net/mbYyR/5/

Comment: Thanks Rob W, you were faster :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to use javascript, then centering it vertically is not possible (as previously stated by others). However, if your goal is to simply have a nice pop-up that allows some flexible width/height, I recommend the following pure CSS solution. Some explanation follows each section for what I did and why I did it.

OPTION #1 HTML (my preferred)

```
<div id="popover-wrapper">
    <div id="popover-direction-setter">
        <div id="actual-popover-div">
            <div id="content-with-unknown-height">
                Content Content with unknown dimensions. Tip should point to the blue dot
                Content with unknown dimensions. Tip should point to the blue dot
                Content with unknown dimensions. Tip should point to the blue dot
            </div>   
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
<div id="target-blue-dot"></div>
```

The triangle `div` is gone, because I am going to use an `:after` pseudo class to apply it since it is purely presentational.

OPTION #1 CSS (note the `#triangle-tip` code was replaced with `#popover-direction-setter:after`)

```
#popover-direction-setter {
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px; /* grow left */
    top:   0px;
    background: #EEE; /* for debugging */
    width: 160px; /*left position of wrapper - 40px for right position of this and triangle tip border size */
}

#actual-popover-div {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: -.5em;
    margin-top: -25px; /* border-radius + half the height of the triangle */
    padding: 0.5em;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 15px;
    min-height: 50px; /* 2 * border radius + half the height of the triangle */
}

#popover-direction-setter:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width:  0;
    height: 0;
    top:           50%;
    margin-top:   -20px;
    border-top:    20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
    border-left:   20px solid black;
    right:        -20px;
}
```

Do not be alarmed by the `#popover-direction-setter` having `width` set. I presume you know the `left` position (since you use it), so this `width` can be pre-calculated and makes a **maximum** width that the pop up will be so that it does not end up flowing off the left side of the browser window. I would think that would be a good thing.

The `min-height` is set on `#actual-popover-div` so that if content is minimal, it looks good with the triangle.

The `top` position of `#actual-popover-div` is offsetting your `em` sizing on the `padding`. The `margin-top` on that element is just bumping up enough to make the arrow sit nicely in the upper corner, and be centered when the `min-height` takes effect.

OPTION #2 HTML (keeps triangle `div` but repositions it)

```
<div id="popover-wrapper">
    <div id="popover-direction-setter">
        <div id="actual-popover-div">
            <div id="content-with-unknown-height">
                Content Content with unknown dimensions. Tip should point to the blue dot
                Content with unknown dimensions. Tip should point to the blue dot
                Content with unknown dimensions. Tip should point to the blue dot
            </div>   
        </div> 
        <div id="triangle-tip"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="target-blue-dot"></div>
```

OPTION #2 CSS remains as you originally had the triangle `div` and eliminates my `:after` pseudoclass code.

I know this does not meet your challenge requirements fully. Again, I agree with others that there is no way currently to position an element centered vertically with an undetermined height. However, if nothing else, others may find my solution good for them.

Comment: Thank you, probably this is the best solution, and if I really want, I can center the content with jQuery. Your solution as a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mbYyR/68/

Comment: Glad that it was close enough for you.

Answer (score 5):

you can fix this problem using jquery, please check [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/mbYyR/66/)

Comment: Because the % depends of the parent block, and every block in your code haven't got any width or height, I think you can't do this without jQuery. That is I think that the correct answer is from Sanooj

Comment: Thank you for your solution, I will probably combine it with the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure `#actual-popover-div` isn't moving because it's set at `position: relative`. Setting it to `postion:absolute` and altering some values seems to get the effect you're looking for.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/mbYyR/8/

Comment: I see than you changed #actual-popover-div's top value to a fixed pixel value, but I would see a solution which works with undetermined content dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to play with is setting the top position, as you are, and also setting a negative margin-top value. You MAY be able to achieve the effect through this method without using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

My pure HTML + CSS solution (needs some cleanup though):

http://tinkerbin.com/f2LIo7RM