# d3js: zooming to a display bigger than svg size

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have gone through a lot of examples, but just could not find what I am looking for. I have a chart which has 54 little bar charts in it. I want to implement following zooming features:

1) By default, the chart is displayed in a `svg` container of size 400x400. On clicking the background of the `svg` container, the whole chart redraws/pops out itself to a bigger display, say 800x800, but without disturbing the other elements in the html page.

2) Each little bar chart has a separate container for itself in the `svg`. On clicking the bar chart, just that chart expands/pops out in a bigger display while rest of the chart is still of the same size.

How can these two features be implemented ??

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You would need two click handlers that add the new graphs either as a separate group in your SVG or a new SVG.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I am unsure of how the new SVG element would render without disturbing other elements. All the examples that I found were zooming the graph in a SVG element, but I want a new zoomed in graph popping out (more likely a new SVG), something like the new zoomed in graph just put on top of the basic graph and then clicking again would remove the new graph leaving the basic one again. How can this be implemented ?

Comment: SVG elements don't affect each other. You can add a new one without disturbing the existing ones.

Comment: Would you consider, instead, allowing the user to zoom/pan to the specific chart? If so, d3 has a nice mousewheel zoom behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're describing is a modal div (or dialog) on top of your current page. If so, you'll need two copies of your charts. One is the original (400x400) and the other is the modal popover (800x800). Since the popover is a completely separate SVG, it can be zoomed differently (showing all 54 little bar charts or one bar chart).

#### Popover

The popover should be clipped so, if you're zooming to show one bar chart, the others will not be visible. You can refine it so when one bar chart is clicked, the popover only draws one bar chart at a time.

The popover can be a simple [div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929825/vertically-centering-a-popover-div) with a high z-order or a dialog. Here's a jQuery [dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/). There are many.

#### Click handlers

You also need click handlers on each chart group the the main SVG group. Alternatively, you could have one click handler for all the bar charts and calculate when you are over the background or an individual bar chart.

```
g.on('click' , function(d){ ...do the zoom... });
```